# CMake: enable_testing in subdirectory with exclude_from_all

Tags: cmake

In my top level CMakeLists.txt I include some external libraries. If I enable testing for my project and the CMakeLists of the external library also calls enable_testing(), those tests are added to my own projects tests, which then cannot be run because the tests of the lib are not built.

I don't want the tests to be built, and I don't want them to clutter my own projects tests. How can I do that?

In my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(some_ext_lib EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL) ' some_ext_libs tests should not be built nor run

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(my_own_stuff) ' here the tests should be run
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `add_subdirectory`, `some_ext_lib` is no longer *external*. You have embedded it into your cmake build. If this is what you want to do, then the simplest way might be to add a variable and conditional logic to control building of the tests in `some_ext_lib`. For example, use `set(BUILD_TESTS_some_ext_lib 0)` before the `add_subdirectory` command, and then modify the `CMakeLists.txt` files for `some_ext_lib` where the tests are inside `if (BUILD_TESTS_some_ext_lib)` logic.

Note that for simplicity one should generally avoid embedding a *top-level* `CMakeLists.txt` of one project in another project. That is, for any given cmake project, there should be only one `CMakeLists.txt` that makes the `find_package` calls and defines the initial option values. Now, with any generalization there are valid exceptions, but when you are just starting out, 
I think you should master the simple ways first.

If `some_ext_lib` is really *external*, then you should have it install its cmake config file that other projects will use with `find_package(some_ext_lib)` commands. But this requires a little more sophistication with cmake.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today and discovered a (slightly dirty) trick to exclude the subproject tests. This is assuming that your `some_ext_lib` CMake file has a `project(some_ext_lib)` directive.

```
add_subdirectory(some_ext_lib EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
add_custom_target(exclude_some_ext_lib_tests ALL 
    COMMAND rm -f "${some_ext_lib_BINARY_DIR}/CTestTestfile.cmake")
```

This effectively tells CMake that there are no tests to be executed in `some_ext_lib`. The advantage of this approach is that it requires no modifications to the `some_ext_lib` sources.