# How to avoid unit test of subdirectory from parent CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, cmake, googletest

I am working with cmake project where one subdirectory is added from parent CMakeLists.txt file.

**In Parent CMakeLists.txt**, I have below line which adds subproject folder.
add_subdirectory(subproject)

**In subdirectory CMakeLists.txt**, I have this line which is not inside any macro.
add_test(NAME sub-tests COMMAND subproject_test)

As of now subproject is always compiles subproject-test.
I want only library of subproject and want to avoid test. So that "make test" command do not show below error.

**LOG:**
Could not find executable /home/root/project/subproject/subproject_test
Looked in the following places:
/home/root/project/subproject/subproject_test
.
.
.

I tried adding EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL, but it do not completely remove test target of subproject.
add_subdirectory(subproject **EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL**)

How to avoid executing subproject's subproject_test to execute during "make test" command.
This issue will help me successfully run component on Jenkins pipe line.

Comment: Can you modify the subprpoject CMakeLists.txt? Then the usual approach is `if (BUILD_SUBPROJ_UT) add_test( ... ) endif()`

Comment: Actually, we are not owner of submodule. We cannot change the subproject/CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: I found one solution for my issue here: [CMake: enable_testing in subdirectory with exclude_from_all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288855/cmake-enable-testing-in-subdirectory-with-exclude-from-all)